# 12.04 LTS distro upgrade to 13.04 -- will it still be LTS?

Tags: upgrade, lts

If one installs Ubuntu 12.04, and does a distribution upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04, does the upgraded version still have five-year Long Term Support?

Comment: the last LTS upgrade is 12.04.3

Answer (score 3):

No, 13.04 is not LTS.

You cannot directly upgrade 12.04 to 13.04. You can upgrade 12.04 LTS to 12.10, and then upgrade 12.10 to 13.04. Both 12.10 and 13.04 are non-LTS.

Ubuntu non-LTS have historically been supported for 18 months. New non-LTS will be supported for 9 months. For example, 12.10 is supported until April 2014 (18 months since October 2012). 13.04 it is supported until January 2014 (9 months since April 2014).

Source: [Releases - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

About NKN's comment: note that *upgrade* has two distinct meanings:

- You can upgrade 12.04.* to 12.04.3, in the sense that you will have
  up-to-date packages for the 12.04 series. This is done by `apt-get dist-upgrade`
  (allows apt-get to install new dependencies if necessary) or `apt-get upgrade`
  (does not allow apt-get to install new
  dependencies).
- You can upgrade 12.04.* to 12.10, so that you will have packages for the 12.10 series. This is done by `do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No.

By upgrading a LTS release to a non-LTS release we will have the support time scheduled for the upgraded release only. For 13.04 this will be [support until January 2014](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

We will however be able to upgrade 12.04 LTS to the next 14.04 LTS version after it was [released in April 2014](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TSeries/ReleaseSchedule).